# nodejs + jade, can we render partial views as we do in ASP.NET?

Tags: node.js, pug, render, partial-views, partials

how can we easily render partial views in JADE using the model-view pattern like this: (pseudocode)

```
response.render('view', model)
and inside  view we have

foreach element in model
    render('_elementPartial', element)
```

or JADE doesnt support partial views this way?

Answer (score 0):

actually i fixed this, didnt know we dont have to pass parameters if we are within same scope
so

if we do something like:

```
p #{someVariable}
include _partial.jade
```

we can also use #{someVariable} from within _partial.jade